# Sails - How to know if a controller or helper has already ended?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have an async function that I want to finish if an event doesn't happen in a few seconds. I've already accomplished that with a timeout. The code is something like this:

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    let finished = false;

    let ws = await sails.helpers.createWebSocketConnection();

    ws.on('message', async function onMessage(data) {
        finished = true;
        return exits.success(ws);
    });

    // If it's taking too long, return undefined
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!finished) {
            return exits.success();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

As you can see, I have a boolean to avoid calling the callback twice, but it doesn't seems like the correct way to do it. Is there a better way to know if `exits.success()` was already called in Sails?

Comment: You list the function as `async` but you're not `await`ing anything. You should probably wrap `setTimeout` in a Promise and await it. Then check `finished`and conditionally return `exits.success`

Comment: @seebiscuit The function is listed as `async` because it has more steps that I've reduced to simplify the code (I've just edited it). What I want to know is if there's a way to rid of the `finished` variable.

Comment: Some further methods of handling `async` in Sails.JS:

https://medium.com/@simon_rsp/handling-async-functions-in-sails-js-552c811b03ed